# Delete empty files - Improve performance of logic

Tags: bash, shell

I am i need to find & remove empty files. The definition of empty files in my use case is a file which has zero lines.

I did try testing the file to see if it's empty However, this behaves strangely as in even though the file is empty it doesn't detect it so.

Hence, the best thing I could write up is the below script which i way too slow given it has to test several hundred thousand files

```
#!/bin/bash

LOOKUP_DIR="/path/to/source/directory"

cd ${LOOKUP_DIR} || { echo "cd failed"; exit 0; }

for fname in $(realpath */*)
do
        if [[ $(wc -l "${fname}" | awk '{print $1}') -eq 0 ]]
        then
                echo "${fname}" is empty
                rm -f "${fname}"
        fi
done
```

Is there a better way to do what I'm after or alternatively, can the above logic be re-written in a way that brings better performance please?

Comment: `find /root/directory -size 0c -delete`?

Comment: @Shawn It's the best solution but not 100% the same. A file can have zero lines (`wc -l` = 0) but more than `0c`.

Comment: @steffen. How? Can you contrive an example?

Comment: `echo -n a > test`

Comment: @MadPhysicist `wc -l` prints the number of *newlines*. If a file doesn't have any (Making it an ill-formed-according-to-POSIX text file), it shows up as having 0 lines according to `wc`.

Comment: It's also a really odd definition of empty.

Comment: `grep -Pzq '\n' "$fname" && echo "line(s)" || echo "zero lines"`

Comment: You can use `wc -l < "$file"` to get rid of the awk. (or `var=$(wc -l "$file"); [ "${var%% *}" -eq 0 ]`) But really, if performance is a problem you might want to do that with any other tool than the shell: the shells aren't exactly fast, and Bash is one of the slower ones.

Comment: Why are you using `realpath */*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is slow beacuse `wc` reads every file to the end, which is not needed for your purpose. This might be what you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

lookup_dir='/path/to/source/directory'

cd "$lookup_dir" || exit
for file in *; do
    if [[ -f "$file" && -r "$file" && ! -L "$file" ]]; then
        read < "$file" || echo rm -f -- "$file"
    fi
done
```

Drop the `echo` after making sure it works as intended.

Another version, calling the `rm` only once, could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

lookup_dir='/path/to/source/directory'

cd "$lookup_dir" || exit
for file in *; do
    if [[ -f "$file" && -r "$file" && ! -L "$file" ]]; then
        read < "$file" || files_to_be_deleted+=("$file")
    fi
done
rm -f -- "${files_to_be_deleted[@]}"
```

**Explanation:**
The core logic is in the line

```
read < "$file" || rm -f -- "$file"
```

The `read < "$file"`  command attempts to read a line from the `$file`. If it succeeds, that is, a line is read, then the `rm` command on the right-hand side of the `||` won't be executed (that's how the `||` works). If it fails then the `rm` command will be executed. In any case, at most one line will be read. This has great advantage over the `wc` command because `wc` would read the whole file.

```
if ! read < "$file"; then rm -f -- "$file"; fi
```

could be used instead. The two lines are equivalent.

Comment: Good catch; is the test really needed ? Silencing `read` stderr seems enough

Comment: @Fravadona I've even added another test (`-r "$file"`). I don't know if the OP would want to `rm` non-regular files or files with no read permission, so I think this way is safer.

Comment: Wow this executed in 7 sec on 600,000 odd files while my script used to take about 20 min or longer depending how busy the system is. I thank you very much.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin - Could you please clarify where in the logic are we checking to see if the file is empty (has no lines in it)

Comment: @usert4jju7 I've added an explanation.

Comment: There's only one thing to be careful about: If you stumble upon a big file with no newlines, you could end up loading the whole thing in memory

Comment: Hello @M.NejatAydin - Would you be able to help me with another performance killer script I have please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430185/remove-duplicate-entries-in-file-optimise-performance

Answer (score 2):

To check a "$fname" is a file and is empty or not, use `[ -s "$fname" ]`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

LOOKUP_DIR="/path/to/source/directory"

for fname in "$LOOKUP_DIR"*/*; do
  if ! [ -s "$fname" ]; then
    echo "${fname}" is empty
    # remove echo when output is what you want
    echo rm -f "${fname}"
  fi
done
```

See: `help test`:

> File operators:
>
> ...
>
> **-s** *FILE*        True if file exists and is not empty.

Comment: Thank you very much Lea. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Yet another method

```sh
wc -l ~/tmp/* 2>/dev/null | awk '$1 == 0 {print $2}' | xargs echo rm
```

This will break if any of your files have whitespace in the name.

To work around that, with awk still

```sh
wc -l ~/tmp/* 2>/dev/null \
| awk 'sub(/^[[:blank:]]+0[[:blank:]]+/, "")' \
| xargs echo rm
```

This works because the `sub` function returns the *number* of substitutions made, which can be treated as a boolean zero/not-zero condition.

Remove the echo to actually delete the files.

Comment: Thank you very much Glenn. Appreciate your help. Nice one liner