# Remove duplicate entries in file - Optimise performance

Tags: bash, shell

There are hundreds of thousands of files that I need to scan everyday to remove duplicate entries from. Each of these files in turn have several thousand records

**Sample input file**

```
2019-10-04,3.9,3.29,5.85,6.15
2019-10-05,3.8,7.02,5.69,6.83
2019-10-05,3.8,8.02,8.69,1.83
2019-10-07,1.8,1.02,4.69,7.83
```

Here is the script I've written for it which takes about an hour or over to complete.

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

LOOKUP_DIR="/path/to/source_files"
CLEANEDUP_DIR="/path/to/cleaned_content"


remove_dup(){
    fname=${1}
    awk -F"," 'prev && ($1 != prev) {print seen[prev]} {seen[$1] = $0; prev = $1} END {print seen[$1]}' "${fname}" > "${CLEANEDUP_DIR}/${fname}"
}

cd ${LOOKUP_DIR}
for k in *.csv
do 
    remove_dup "${k}" &
done

wait
```

The way to check duplicates is to look at the first field & if there are multiple entries for this field (date in this case) only the last line with this date needs to be retained & the rest removed.

Is there a way to optimise the logic I've written please?

Comment: Are the lines ordered by the first field?

Comment: Is it possible that a file has records `2019-10-05,...`, `2019-10-07,...`, `2019-10-05,...`, in that order?

Comment: Is it only column 1 that is supposed to be included when you decide if it's a duplicate or not? If it is, does it matter which of the two rows with `2019-10-05` it picks?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin - Yes it is possible to have the enties int he order you've mentioned wihch is 2019-10-05,..., 2019-10-07,..., 2019-10-05,...

Comment: @M.NejatAydin - The lines are mostly ordered. However, I won't rule out the possibility that they aren't. Just like you've asked in your second question where a date might repeat itself out of place.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Yes it's only column 1 we need to use to determine if an entry is a duplicate. Also, the last of the occurrence should be retained.

Comment: @usert4jju7 Ok, should it keep the last duplicate as it looks in the file _before_ sorting or _after_ sorting?

Comment: Ted - The latest entry is always added to the end of file. So, it should be before sorting

Comment: Do you just want to remove the duplicate entries from each file, or are you talking about removing duplicated entries that must be removed even if in different files?

Comment: If you have hundreds of thousands of files then you hardly can process them all at the same time, unless you both have enough CPU and IO to back it up. You might want to use GNU parallel for determining the right number of processes to spawn given your hardware configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tac thefile | sort -urst, -k1,1
```

---

> Optimise performance

Rewrite it in a single programming language. Do not use processes - use threads for each file. For scripting, use Python or Ruby. For compiling, use C++ or C. This took like just less than an hour to write, and most probably is immensely faster than `fork()`ing a new process for each file:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <filesystem>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

std::string algo(const std::filesystem::path& file) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> lines;
    std::ifstream ffile(file);
    std::string line;
    std::string field;
    size_t pos;
    while (std::getline(ffile, line)) {
        pos = 0;
        for (auto&& c : line) {
            if (c == ',') {
                break;
            }
            pos++;
        }
        field = line.substr(0, pos);
        lines.insert_or_assign(std::move(field), std::move(line));
    }
    std::ostringstream of;
    for (auto&& i : lines) {
        of << i.second << '\n';
    }
    return of.str();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const std::filesystem::path p(argv[1]);
    std::vector<
        std::pair<
            std::string, std::future<std::string>
            >
        > results;
    if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(p)) {
        std::cout << algo(p) << '\n';
    } else {
        for (auto&& f : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(p)) {
            if (f.is_regular_file()) {
                results.emplace_back(f.path(), std::async(algo, f.path()));
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto&& r : results) {
        std::cout
            << "=== " << r.first << " ===\n\n"
            << r.second.get() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello - Many thanks. Regarding the tac solution, what is the purpose of running a tac & also, the purpose of sorting in reverse using 'r'  please?

Comment: `tac` with stable sort should preserve the last entry. `sort -su -k1.1` will preserve the first. Well, the `r` is that so that lines are ordered like the input, it's doing nothing particular there.

Comment: Will removing 'r' option result in incorrect result? I ask as the content is sorted in reverse in the end. I want the latest record at the end which ends up being the first record due to the use of -r option

Comment: No, it has no effect. Well, just try it ;)

Comment: Cool Thank you. This looks quite promising & easy to understand. Trying out now

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question and you want to remove any duplicated records from within each file, then using a pair of arrays in `awk`, the first using a counter as the index so record order is maintained storing the 5 fields joined by `SUBSEP` for the stored value. The second array indexed by the 5 fields joinded by `SUBSEP` holds the record as the stored value. This allows a simple check if the 5 fields have been seen before using the `index in array` test.

Rather than writing the script in `remove_dup()`, just write an executable `awk` script that is called from `remove_dup()`. The script could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="," }

{ if ($1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3 SUBSEP $4 SUBSEP $5 in array)
    next
  order[++n] = $1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3 SUBSEP $4 SUBSEP $5
  array[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5] = $0
}

END {
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    print array[order[i]]
}
```

(above a record is only stored if the joined fields do NOT already exist as an index in `array` ensuring all duplicates are removed, keeping the order of the first occurrence in tact and discarding all others)

Then you can modify your script as:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

LOOKUP_DIR="/path/to/source_files"
CLEANEDUP_DIR="/path/to/cleaned_content"
AWKSCRIPT="/path/to/executable/awkscript"

remove_dup(){
    fname=${1}
    $AWKSCRIPT "${fname}" > "${CLEANEDUP_DIR}/${fname}"
}

cd ${LOOKUP_DIR}
for k in *.csv
do 
    remove_dup "${k}" &
done

wait
```

(note the addition of the path to the executable `awkscript` stored in the variable `AWKSCRIPT`)

That should do what you are after.

Comment: Many thanks David. I'll give this a go & report back

Comment: You didn't mention a possible cause of bottleneck which is spawning a few hundred thousand of processes that read and write at the same time to the disk.

Comment: Thank you David. This does the job just like the sort command above. Your solution & the one from Kamil take exactly the same time to complete.

Comment: Glad it helped. Goes to show there is always more than one way to *skin-the-cat* with `awk`.